# Reading data and displaying

Tags: extjs4

I am trying to get all Books from the server (local `PHP` script), that has a book `ID` of `1`.

I think i will have to send a `GET` request with `ID` 1, so that the `PHP` script will return the records for `ID 1`.

When i searched i found out that i should make use of `Ext.ModelManager.getModel` to get this done. But i am unable to find any examples that would help me to do this.

Can someone help me out.

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using? And what have you tried?

Comment: I am using ext js 4, I have created a Model and Store. I have no idea as in how to send the GET request with the parameter. and then get the JSON results and display it in a form

Comment: Try to read through this tutorial http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/getting_started and actually do a sample application step-by-step

Comment: Yes i will, but can you tell me how to send the `ID` as parameter through a `GET` request. I don't think the getting started guide has that.

Comment: No, because this question has very little sense. And once you read their guide and will have better handle on MVC structure you will understand relationship between store/model and your server back end better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your store, add proxy and set extraParams.

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'your url'
},
listeners: {
    'beforeload': function (t,n) {            
        this.proxy.extraParams.Id = yourId
},
```

Comment: Thank you fo your reply. What does `beforeload` do ? do i have to call it from the controller ?

Comment: You have to do it in your store. In controller you can call yourStore.load(). beforeload event - Fires before a request is made for a new data object. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-beforeload